# Java Vector getting erased before return

Tags: java, generics, vector

**I solved it**, but I don't know if my solution is the best. So any helpful information is welcome

I'm trying to make a method which given a vector eg: [a, b, c, e] should return the Vector [[a,b],[a,c],[a,e]]. I'm using it for BFS.

```
    public Vector<Vector<E>> routesFrom(Vector<E> edges) {
    E source = edges.firstElement();
    Vector<Vector<E>> returner = new Vector<>();
    Vector<E> insert = new Vector<>();
    for (int i=1; i<edges.size(); i++) {
        insert.add(edges.firstElement());
        insert.add(edges.elementAt(i));
        returner.add(insert);
        insert.removeAllElements();
    }
    return returner;
}
```

This is my code, but it's malfunctioning in 2 places, first when i add "insert" into "returner" instead of adding the new value next to the old value it erases all the values:
Instead of [[a,b],[a,c]] i get [[a,c],[a,c]].
And then finally before it is returned it all gets erased and the final return is [[],[],[]].

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

*My solution*

```
public Vector<Vector<E>> routesFrom(Vector<E> edges) {
    E source = edges.firstElement();
    Vector<Vector<E>> returner = new Vector<>();
    Vector<E> insert = new Vector<>();
    for (int i=1; i<edges.size(); i++) {
        insert.add(edges.firstElement());
        insert.add(edges.elementAt(i));
        returner.add(castObj(insert.clone()));
        insert.removeAllElements();
    }
    return returner;
}

private Vector<E> castObj(Object object) {
    Vector<E> returner = new Vector<>();
    for (Object o : (Vector) object) 
        returner.add((E)o);
    return returner;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert.removeAllElements();
```

In Java, Objects are passed by reference. Since this is the same object you pass into the `returner` Vector, when you remove its elements, the `returner` Vector also loses those elements.

Fix: Create a new Vector inside the loop.

```
Vector<Vector<E>> returner = new Vector<>();
for (int i=1; i<edges.size(); i++) {
    Vector<E> insert = new Vector<>();
    insert.add(edges.firstElement());
    insert.add(edges.elementAt(i));
    returner.add(insert);
}
```

---

Your new answer looks ok, but I have a couple of suggestions. `clone()` is not a good method to use in general, it's usually better to create a new collection passing the old one into it's constructor.

So you can replace:

```
returner.add(castObj(insert.clone()));
```

With:

```
returner.add(new Vector<E>(insert);
```

This also saves you the trouble of casting the object.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just found a solution and posted it in the original post. It uses clone() whenever I insert. Could you check it out and tell me if it's okay or if it's going to give me problems.

Comment: Very well. I felt that it could problematic. 
Thanks again for the help Mr. Noob :)